# How to reload window when someone is not on the screen of the site.But on the screen window should not be reload

Tags: javascript, json

I am using this code to reload the window. I want that when someone is on the screen it should not be reloaded.But if someone is not on the screen it should be auto-reload again and again.

```
<html>
<header>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script> -->
</header>
<body onload="AutoRefresh(1000)">
    <p id="req">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>

<p>
<script src="index.js">
     function AutoRefresh( t ) {
               setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
      }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if someone is not on the screen it doesn't matter if you reload or not? Please explain why you want to implement this?

Comment: Just for education purpose for increasing page views of any webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```js
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}
 

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    // do something when inactive
  } else {
    // do something when active
  }
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
```